# Azure Storage zip file corrupted after upload (using Azure Storage Blob client library for Java)

Tags: azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-for-java

problem: zip file with csv files generated from data seems to be corrupted after upload to Azure Blob Storage.

zip file before upload looks like this:

[image]

and everything works fine. That same zip file after upload is corrupted and looks like this:
[image]

During upload I use Azure Storage Blob client library for Java (v. 12.7.0, but I tried also previous versions). This is code I use (similar to example provided in [SDK readme file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-storage-blob_12.0.0/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/README.md)):

```
public void uploadFileFromPath(String pathToFile, String blobName) {
     BlobClient blobClient = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
     blobClient.uploadFromFile(pathToFile);
}
```

And I get uploaded file:

[image]

When I download file **directly from storage explorer**, file is already corrupted.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please try to download file with code `blobClient.downloadToFile`.

Comment: The file is already corrupted in storage. There's no difference in downloading it by java app or through Storage Explorer on Azure portal. In both cases zip file is corrupted.

Comment: If you directly upload the file  via portal, is it ok for you?

Comment: @JimXu Yes. When I upload file via portal everything works fine. But content type is different: "application/x-zip-compressed" instead of "application/octet-stream".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was my fault. I didn't close ZipOutputStream before uploading file. It is not much of a problem when you use try with resources and just want to generate local file. But in my case I want to upload file to Blob Storage (still in the try section). File was incomplete (not closed) so it appeared on storage with corrupted data. This is what I should do from the very beginning.

```
private void addZipEntryAndDeleteTempCsvFile(String pathToFile, ZipOutputStream zipOut,
        File file) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("Adding zip entry: {}", pathToFile);
    zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pathToFile));
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zipOut.closeEntry();
        file.delete()
    }
    zipOut.close(); // missing part
}
```

After all, thank you for your help @JimXu. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I suggest you use the following method to upload you zip file

```
public void uploadFromFile(String filePath, ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions, BlobHttpHeaders headers, Map<String,String> metadata, AccessTier tier, BlobRequestConditions requestConditions, Duration timeout)
```

We can use the method to set content type

For example

```
BlobHttpHeaders headers = new BlobHttpHeaders()
     .setContentType("application/x-zip-compressed");
 Integer blockSize = 4* 1024 * 1024; // 4MB;
 ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions = new ParallelTransferOptions(blockSize, null, null);
blobClient.uploadFromFile(pathToFile,parallelTransferOptions,headers,null, AccessTier.HOT, null, null);
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobclient.uploadfromfile?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_BlobClient_uploadFromFile_java_lang_String_com_azure_storage_blob_models_ParallelTransferOptions_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobHttpHeaders_java_util_Map_java_lang_String_java_lang_String__com_azure_storage_blob_models_AccessTier_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobRequestConditions_java_time_Duration_)

Comment: Tried that, with same effect. I also tried with different block sizes and content types.

Comment: @MacKarczewski According to the situation, please try to use method `upload`. It uploads the file with stream.

Comment: Tried that also. Same effect. It seems like SDK cuts off some part of file data during upload.  I tried it on a few different machines with different environment.